# Where are the details for the different Workitem types in TFS oData service?

Tags: tfs, odata

Using the TFS oData service I see only a generic WorkItem class which has a Type property. How can I access properties such as Mitigation, Contingency Plan, etc. for the Risk type, or Corrective Action for the Issue type?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific class for each WorkItem, because you can customize and name them as you want, therefor the generic WorkItem class is used. If you want to get the value of a specific field, load the WorkItem and use following (with the fieldname you need):

```
wi.Fields["System.AssignedTo"].Value
```

Comment: The TFS OData service does not seem to return the fields collection - looks like I'll have to dig into the service code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the oData service. Is there any reason why not to use the normal TFS API?

Comment: I never managed to get authentication working - I wrote a web service and tried to get windows creds passed through to the TFS server using <authentication mode="Windows" /> and <identity impersonate="true" /> but always got unauthorized.  Do you know of any reason why that would not work?

Comment: Depends on what your service is doing. By default the service is using the credentials of the ApplicationPool it is running in, if we talk about a web service. If you want to "forward" the credentials of the user calling your service, this might be a bit more difficult. You can connect to TFS like this `connectedTPC = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUrl, new TfsClientCredentials(credentials));`  but no idea how to get connected users credentials, I used it by providing user and password.

Comment: I'm now trying to do this rather than use the oData service. But just how do I get the connected user credentials? Anyone?